# Showing MarkDown Flutter from source of a link

Tags: string, flutter, markdown

I would like to use `flutter_markdown` package.. So here is the example:
`Markdown(data: markdownSource);` where `markdownSource` here is a String, but what I would like to do is..... I have md String which I store inside `https://mylink.co.id/trial.md` and is there a way to read `https://mylink.co.id/trial.md` and show it using `Markdown()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. Create the markdown string and save it in a server. Make an API call and get it's content. (don't miss to await this step). Then you can use the response value as data:response

Comment: Hi I open a question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72681532/how-to-load-md-link-which-is-stored-inside-a-md-link-flutter would you like to take a look