# How to load md link which is stored inside a md link--Flutter

Tags: flutter, file, assets

I am currently trying to show md file using `MarkDown` as a package from `flutter_markdown` and I  find this source https://stackoverflow.com/a/63567194/13240914
It is stated that to load md file from asset using

```
future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString
            ("assets/manual/" + file),
```

but, is there a way to load md file from a link ( something like: "http://mdlink.co.id/data.md" ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetworkAssetBundle if you are trying to fetch it from a network like

```
NetworkAssetBundle(Uri baseUrl);
```